# Angular ng-show select option child options

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, drop-down-menu

So if I have a selection like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="beneSelect">Select your benefit</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="beneSelect" >
        <option ng-repeat="descr in claim.claimBenes" 
                data-ng-model="claimInfo.providerName">{{ descr.descr }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And below that, if the 'descr' has a sibling property that has data, to `ng-show` an selection  `option`, how or what is the best way to do this?

So for instance, if the **JSON** data I am pulling has 9 different properties and in the initial select I am showing like:

```
  "id": "%2fooTA9gmtHE8IJ13CdcAww%3d%3d",
  "planTypeId": 1,
  "benefitTypeId": 11,
  "benefCode": "LHCFSA",
  "descr": "Limited Health Care FSA (1/1/2015 - 12/31/2015)",
  "askSecIns": false,
  "askResidual": false,
  "hasFunds": true,
  "startDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
  "endDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
  "expenseTypes": [
    {
      "id": 56,
      "descr": "General Dental Care"
    },
    {
      "id": 52,
      "descr": "General Vision Care"
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "descr": "Orthodontia"
    },
    {
      "id": 58,
      "descr": "Preventive Care"
    }
  ],
```

If the `expenseTypes` "HAS" data, then another select would show, otherwise, just the one select would show. Actually, I would show a new `<div>` with HTML in it with another `<select>`.

Not sure the best way to tackle this in Angular. Suggestions with examples please?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Can use the length of the `expenseTypes` array as a boolean

```
ng-if="claim.expenseTypes.length"
```

Comment: If I do as a length and the expenseType is an object, would that length be if the object >= 1 or how would that work since not an actual bool?

Comment: you were showing as array. Generally best to keep type consistent or set to null maybe. An object has no length. do you control the data source api?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to the API - but it will have some limitations. Can you show me in this context as you would represent? What I mean is, do I have to say length is anything at all or just leave as is?

Comment: depends on what api will be sending

Answer (score 0):

I guess You are looking for this....

maybe it will help you with some ideas....

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function InputController() {
    var secondary = {
        A: [1, 2, 3],
        B: [3, 4, 5]
      },
      vm = this;

    vm.primary = ['A', 'B'];
    vm.selectedPrimary = vm.primary[0];

    vm.onPrimaryChange = function() {
      vm.secondary = secondary[vm.selectedPrimary];
    };
  }

  angular.module('inputs', [])
    .controller('InputCtrl', InputController);

}());
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="inputs" ng-controller="InputCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3>Primary</h3>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selectedPrimary" ng-options="item for item in ctrl.primary" ng-change="ctrl.onPrimaryChange()"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3>Secondary</h3>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selectedSecondary" ng-options="item for item in ctrl.secondary"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```